# "Punt" printouts

Tags: meaning-in-context

What does punt mean in "Punt printouts, pens, and paper cuts. Acrobat Reader lets you fill and e‑sign forms faster on any device."? Does it mean to delay in this context? Thank you!
[image]

Comment: It looks like they're using it to mean "get rid of".  This is a strange way to use the word *punt*.  It's understandable, because in gridiron football, when you *punt* a ball, you are getting rid of it, but that's not how we normally use the word *punt*.

Comment: I think it's a word that means "get rid of" that starts with a "p", like the other words in that sentence. They chose alliteration over using natural language and being precise in meaning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the word is used in an office context, "punt" is referring to putting off something, such a committee may do for a business decision, indefinitely. Politicians may punt on an issue, passing it on to their successors.

So Adobe is using the term in the sense of "avoid."

Answer (score 1):

I would say that 'punt' in this context means 'decide not to include [in your workflow]'.

> Punt verb transitive
> US informal
>
> If you punt something, you decide not to do or include it:
>
> We were running out of time, so we decided to punt the sightseeing and
> just go shopping.

[Punt (Cambridge Dictionary)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/punt)